# PHP served image always corrupt

Tags: php, apache

Whenever I try to serve an image with PHP, it will both state the image is broken/corrupt, and give the following warning in Google Chrome:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   image/png

However, the situation is as follows;

1. This script runs fine on multiple servers, just not on this one.
2. I have used multiple images and extensions
3. The images are working perfectly fine if I put them in an `img`src as a base64 decoded image
4. For testing purposes, I have put it on the first line in my index.php, didn't work
5. My files aren't UTF-8 BOM
6. I personally can't see any surprise-headers

Examples of what I've tried:

```
$imgpath = 'assets/img/dropdown-arrow.png';
$type      = pathinfo($imgpath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data      = file_get_contents($imgpath);
$base64    = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
header('Content-Type: image/png;'); // also tried with charset=UTF-8 and such
echo base64_decode($base64);
exit();
```

Example 2 (the working on other servers example):

```
// Set the content type header - in this case image/png
header('Content-Type: image/png; charset=UTF-8');
// integer representation of the color black (rgb: 0,0,0)
$background = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

// removing the black from the placeholder
imagecolortransparent($img, $background);

// turning off alpha blending (to ensure alpha channel information
// is preserved, rather than removed (blending with the rest of the
// image in the form of black))
imagealphablending($img, false);

// turning on alpha channel information saving (to ensure the full range
// of transparency is preserved)
imagesavealpha($img, true);

// Output the image
imagepng($img);
```

--- So, again; I have already cut my framework out as the middle man, trying to run this straight from the index.php's first line.

so, for some weird reason, the moment I set the `content-type` to `image/png`;; everything goes downhill.

Would anybody have any clue as to why this is happening? Is this something I missed with my code? Is it something I can't possibly fix with my code (server-side)? Did I just miss something extremely obvious?

---

### Basic Serverinfo:

I'm running on Apache 2.4.5 with PHP-FPM. (Though switching to PHP-FASTCGI changed nothing) on PHP 7.2.3

---

### Response Headers:

**Connection:** Keep-Alive

**Content-Type:** image/png

**Date:** Fri, 13 Jul 2018 19:51:37 GMT

**Keep-Alive:** timeout=5, max=99

**Server:** Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

**Transfer-Encoding:** chunked

---

### UPDATE/FIX

Apparently, someone (Not me, really!) put a space before the `<?php` tag in one small file which was being included across the MVC. Removing that space fixed every issue. It took quite a few hours to find, so, the lesson for anyone reading: Make sure you keep your code neatly formatted and always put your `<?php` tags at the very start.

Comment: In your first example, you seem to be following instructions for an img tag.  You wouldn't do all this manipulation if you're just streaming the file.  Just set the header content-type and use readfile

Comment: Thank you so much for your last UPDATE/FIX.
I had i problem with Mapserver Mapscript WMS output to png that was invalid,
and then i found out that <?php var starting on line 2 .........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can output it directly, no need to do a base64_encode/decode

```
$imgpath = 'assets/img/dropdown-arrow.png';
$data    = file_get_contents($imgpath);
header('Content-Type: image/png;');
echo $data;
exit();
```

Comment: Uhm... thank you, that actually fixed it directly in the index.php! However, now it's still not working within the bounds of the framework... Do you have any idea how I could debug/find what's causing this? There is nothing being printed or anything, yet the exact same function doesn't work. I have turned off all other header and encoding functions my framework uses.

Comment: What do you mean by "bounds of the framework"? Could you be more specific like, which framework, how you are trying to use the image?

Comment: It's a custom framework, but just a conventional MVC. However, I just started copy-pasting the image through the steps the routing takes and just figured out from which moment onward it's all going wrong. This one, I'll have to solve on my own. The base64 thing was just a testing mistake in the end, but I will mark your answer as the correct one since I tested poorly myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in example 2, your header says that your data is utf8 encoded.
Why?
your data is a binary file
and no utf8 encoded

Comment: For testing purposes, my bad.

Comment: This is a great comment on a question, but not an answer.